# Spring JDBC for SQL Server - Using SQLXML datatypes yields SQLServerException: Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar(max) is not allowed

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, sqlxml

I'm trying to make use of a SQL Server stored procedure that uses XML in/out parameters using a Spring SimpleJdbcCall as per this example from the Spring 3.2 documentation (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html):

```
public class JdbcActorDao implements ActorDao {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall procReadActor;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.procReadActor =
                new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                        .withProcedureName("read_actor");
    }

    public Actor readActor(Long id) {
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("in_id", id);
        Map out = procReadActor.execute(in);
        Actor actor = new Actor();
        actor.setId(id);
        actor.setFirstName((String) out.get("out_first_name"));
        actor.setLastName((String) out.get("out_last_name"));
        actor.setBirthDate((Date) out.get("out_birth_date"));
        return actor;
    }

    //  ... additional methods
}
```

My implementation is as such:

```
@Repository
public class ObjectDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Value("${db.sp.getObject}")
    private String spName;

    private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;


    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.jdbcCall=
                new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withProcedureName(spName);
    }

    public SQLXML getDbObjectById(Integer id) {

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("objectId", id, Types.INTEGER);


        Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);

        return (SQLXML) out.get("OutputXML");
    }

}
```

I've tested the connection parameters out with other database transactions and these have been successful, but when attempting to read an output parameter that uses an XML variable, I'm presented with a BadSqlGrammarException as per the below

```
EXECEPTION

    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

ROOT CAUSE

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call spXML_Wrapper(?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is  c om  .microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1036)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1070)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:387)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:350)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:181)
    com.test.dao.ObjectDao.getDbObjectById(InvoiceDaoImpl.java:59)
    ........

ROOT CAUSE 

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Implicit conversion from data type xml to nvarchar(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:332)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1072)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$6.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1070)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1020)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1070)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:387)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:350)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:181)
    com.test.dao.ObjectDao.getDbObjectById(InvoiceDaoImpl.java:59)
    .......
```

I've checked that the stored procedure itself is up to scratch - executes fine. Does anyone have any experience with such an error or have any alternative suggestions to reading XML output from stored procedures using the Spring framework?

Other info:

Spring 3.2

Tomcat 7.0

Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked this up so it's just a theory, but my guess is that the XML type used by the SQL Server JDBC driver is not using a standard datatype value used in `java.sql.Types`.

What I would do is write a simple, standalone JDBC program that prints the `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType()` value of the data type returned by your stored procedure.  If that integer is not listed in `java.sql.Types`, then chances are that Spring is defaulting it to a string value, and you'll have to find a way to override how it is handling data type inference.

I don't think you're going to be able to pull this off using a SimpleJdbcCall; I think you'll have to fall back to using JdbcTemplate, unfortunately.  Spring's handling of data types in stored procedures appears to be pretty limited.

Comment: Thanks for this. In the end, I did as you suggested and reverted to a JdbcTemplate; less graceful but more functional.